# How can I extract text from image respecting the distance between words?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to extract text from an image of printed text. Along with the text itself, I am interested in detecting the spaces between the words as well. The spaces between words are not consistent (deliberate) and that is something I want detected.

To achieved this I first had to extract the text lines. I achieved that using the projection profile code attached (code copied from one of the answers by ImageAnalyst). 
[image]

One way I thought of achieving this was by counting the number of white pixels between the words, if I know the number of pixels taken by a single space (say n), I could just determine the number of spaces by dividing the white pixels between the words by this 'n' to get the number of spaces.

I tried that but it did not go as planned, the results are very conflicting, even when compared against known ground truth values. Determining a baseline of every text line is proving to be difficult, for a single space between two words I am getting different pixel count. This is because as counting the white pixels from letter d to b is different from counting the white pixels from c to s (the white pixels within the curve of c is also sometimes counted.)

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

code I used :

```
clc;  
close all;  
clear;  
fontSize = 16; 
img = imread('Lines.png');

[rows, columns, dim] = size(img);
if dim > 1  
    grayImage = img(:, :, 2);
end

% Display the original gray scale image.
subplot(3, 3, 1);
imshow(grayImage, []);
title('Original image', 'FontSize', fontSize);
axis on;

set(gcf, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'OuterPosition', [0 0 1 1]); % Enlarge figure to full screen.

% Threshold the image.
binaryImage = grayImage < 210;  

% Get rid of small areaas of 14 pixels or less
binaryImage = ~bwareaopen(binaryImage, 15);
subplot(2, 3, 2);
imshow(binaryImage);
title('Binary Image', 'FontSize', fontSize);
axis on;

% Vertical Profile
verticalProfile = sum(binaryImage, 2); 
subplot(3, 3, [2 3]);
plot(verticalProfile, 'b');
grid on;
title('Vertical Profile', 'FontSize', fontSize);

rowsWithText = verticalProfile < 600;  

% Find top and bottom lines
topLines = find(diff(rowsWithText) == 1);
bottomLines = find(diff(rowsWithText) == -1);

for j = 1 : length(topLines) 
    topRow = topLines(j);
    bottomRow = bottomLines(j);
    thisLine = binaryImage(topRow:bottomRow, :);
    subplot(3, 3, [4 5 6]);
    imshow(thisLine, []);
    axis on;
    caption = sprintf('Line %d of the text', j);
    title(caption, 'FontSize', fontSize);

    % Horizontal profile
    horizontalProfile = sum(thisLine, 1);
    subplot(3, 3, [7 8 9]);
    plot(horizontalProfile);
    grid on;
    caption = sprintf('Horizontal Profile of Line %d of the text', j);
    title(caption, 'FontSize', fontSize);

    promptMessage = sprintf('lines %d', j);
    titleBarCaption = 'Continue?';
    button = questdlg(promptMessage, titleBarCaption, 'Continue', 'Cancel', 'Continue');
    if strcmpi(button, 'Cancel')
        return;
    end  
end
msgbox('Done!');
```

picture : [Image of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmZX3.png)

Comment: How exactly are you defining the horizontal profile? Since the data appears to be very clean, one solution might be to define the horizontal profile a bit more crisply, e.g. convert the single line image `L` to boolean with black=0, white=1 if it isn't already and then set horizontal profile to `min(L, [], 1)`.

Comment: @verbatross I edit my question, and I added my program and the picture I am working in. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try playing around with something like this:

```
% define min length of gap between words; play around with this value
min_gap_length = 5;

% define wordStarts/wordEnds like you've defined topLines/bottomLines
wordStarts = find(diff(horizontalProfile) == -1);
wordEnds = find(diff(horizontalProfile) == 1);
if wordStarts(1) > wordEnds(1)
    wordStarts = [1, wordStarts];
end
if wordEnds(end) < wordStarts(end)
    wordEnds = [wordEnds, length(horizontalProfile)];
end

% restrict wordStarts/wordEnds to gaps of over min_gap_length
I = wordStarts(2:end) - wordEnds(1:end-1) > min_gap_length;
wordStarts = wordStarts([true, I]);
wordEnds = wordEnds([I, true]);
```